# Using a macro to define an include file

Tags: c++

To make a long story short, I'm working on some code that needs different header files based on various configuration options. I could do something like this:

```cpp
#if OPTION == A
#include "relative/path/to/file/a.hpp"
#elseif OPTION == B
#include "relative/path/to/file/b.hpp"
#elseif OPTION = ...
...
#endif
```

This would work, but it seems like a really ugly solution for what could potentially be more than a handful files. I could also simply include all the various header files, but that, too, seems like a bit of an ugly solution, and it could pose problems in the future if files (for some horrible reason) start redefining the same objects. The idea I had was that something like the following would be nice, particularly in the context of how the rest of the code is written:

```cpp
#define QUOTE(str) #str
#define STRINGIFY(A,B) QUOTE(A##B)
...
#include STRINGIFY(relative/path/to/option/,OPTION)
```

The problem with this seems to be two-fold:

1. The `OPTION` definition doesn't expand properly inside `STRINGIFY`.
2. If there are any forward slashes in the path name, `STRINGIFY` fails altogether, with g++ giving me an error along the lines of the following:

> error: pasting "/" and "OPTION" does not give a valid preprocessing token

I can't seem to find any real information on why `/` is a bad character for the C++ preprocessor, just a few articles saying that you should just put `"/"` in and rely on automatic C++ string concatenation (which doesn't work in an `#include` statement). I'm willing to consider design alternatives if I'm just trying to do something really dumb, but I'd also like to figure out why this isn't working.

EDIT: I should make the clarification that I'm working on a codebase originally designed by a group of scientists. Reasonable coding conventions and typical expectations for how a code gets used go completely out the window. This code will probably be modified at least as many times as it gets used, often by people who have spent their entire careers writing Fortran 77 and think object-oriented programming is some new-fangled invention that just makes your code harder to understand.

Comment: Perhaps the last part of https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html#Stringizing will be useful to you. It shows how to stringize the result of an expansion by using 2 levels.

Comment: Although side-stepping the issue, what about putting your 'ugly' code in a well named header and `#include`-ing that where needed? Still doesn't help adding new features but code is read many more times than it is written, in general.

Comment: I'm with @clcto here, with the additional observation that the trickier your preprocessor magic is, the more time you're going to spend explaining what it does to other people who are dealing with the code-base.

Comment: *"... and think object-oriented programming is some new-fangled invention that just makes your code harder to understand"*, yet you want to use some relatively complicated macro logic to make this work, obfuscate the header files that you are using, and make it harder to change in the future. What happens when someone tries to find out why you are getting a compiler error for not found header file `relative/path/to/file/B.hpp` and cannot find where that is even being used in the code base?

Comment: Again, I get that there may be better practices, and I'm happy to try or consider the ones that fit inside my design constraints. But no one to date has told me *why* what I'm currently trying doesn't work, i.e., why a forward slash seems to break everything.

Answer (score 0):

When writing macros it is essential to look at the output after preprocessing. With `gcc` thats the `-E` option.

To include different files I would rely on your build tools rather than macro voodoo. For example when the code is

```
include option
```

Then `gcc -E -option=\"foo.h\"` [yields](https://godbolt.org/z/1v3zzEKP6)

```
include "foo.h"
```

Note that I ommitted the `#` here, otherwise preprocessing would fail due to not finding `"foo.h"`.

Comment: There are two issues with that: 1) although I'm using GCC, the code needs to support a variety of compilers (currently at least five), and 2) that fixes the problem of OPTION not being expanded properly, but I would still have to hardcode the entire path. Because it's specified using a relative path in various parts of the code, I would prefer to have only the header file itself determined by OPTION.

Comment: @JacobFields every compiler has an option to define a preprocessor symbol. And build tools typically handle that transparently

Comment: That may be the case, but it unfortunately doesn't address the fact that hard-coding a path is less than ideal for my use-case scenario. To be fair, if I had my way, I would completely rewrite the build procedure and code organization for this project so that I could reduce the choice of header to a single option in CMake, but that's not a realistic option right now.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar, searched around and found this post, and after trying few things I think I can help you.

So, your approach:

```
#define QUOTE(str) #str
#define STRINGIFY(A,B) QUOTE(A##B)
...
#include STRINGIFY(relative/path/to/option/,OPTION)
```

As I understand from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html doesn't work because when using `##` to paste tokens, the result must be a valid token, where something like `path/to/file.hpp` is not a valid preprocessing token.

Now, I think that you only need to have a macro which holds the path plus the token to be replaced. Well, you don't really need to add the relative path if you are using the `-I` flag. Your macro could look like `#define myMacro relative/path/to/file/OPTION.hpp`, then you just need to define `OPTION` and pass it to one macro so `OPTION` gets replaced with its value and then another macro to stringize. These two levels of macros are described here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html#Stringizing

The following example will ilustrate both cases (with/without `-I` flag).

Consider this directory structure:

```
.   
|-- a.c 
|-- headers
|   |-- A.hpp
|   `-- B.hpp
`-- makefile
```

Where a.c:

```
#define header OPTION.hpp
#define xstr(x) #x
#define str(x) xstr(x)
#include str(header)
```

makefile:

```
PATH_OPTION ?= headers/A
OPTION ?= A

.PHONY: all 
all: a.c 
        cpp -D OPTION=${PATH_OPTION} $<
        cpp -I./headers -D OPTION=${OPTION} $<
```

A.hpp

```
#warning Including A.hpp
1
```

B.hpp

```
#warning Including B.hpp
2
```

With this, you can call `make` which by default will include `headers/A.hpp` and you should be able to see both approaches (with/without `-I` flag) working and printing to stdout the corresponding warning.

To include `headers/B.hpp` you would do `make OPTION=B` or `make PATH_OPTION=headers/B` depending on the approach you take.

I also tried with `g++` instead of `cpp` and it works as well.